# Absolute quotient-remainder question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I can write any natural number $a$ in the form $a = xb + s$, where $x, b$ are some integers (with $b$ $odd$) and $|s| \leq \frac{b}{2}$.

Going further I can say that $\frac{a}{b} \geq x \implies a=\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor b + s$, with $s\geq0$, and similarly $\frac{a}{b} < x \implies a=(\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor +1) b + s$, with $s\leq0$.

With this new expression, I am now asked to show that $|s| \leq \frac{b-1}{2}$, which would finish up what I am being asked to prove, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: $b-1=2s$ might help.

Comment: Where do I get this from?

Comment: I was working backwards, but it follows from $b-1$ non-zero residues each of which have an additive inverse in those same residues.